# Installing Gfx Tablet

Tags: software-installation

I wanted to install this software : http://rfc2822.github.io/GfxTablet/

On CS50 Appliance ( Harvard's CS Operating System) which is based on Xubuntu and ultimately Ubuntu.

I downloaded the binary file, renamed it to "networktablet",

Then typed the following commands in the terminal after moving the terminal directory to the place I downloaded the file.

chmod a+x networktablet

Then, sudo ./networktablet

But it resulted in the error :

./networktablet: 2: ./networktablet: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string

Comment: I believe this is off-topic, as it is an unofficial deriative of Ubuntu. You might have more luck asking at [unix.se].

Comment: Did you download the tarball/zip archive and rename it to "networktablet"?

Comment: Actually, there are different instructions if I download the tarball/zip archive. And there is a different error when I do that.

When I compile the files inside "driver-uinput" through make,

clang: error: cannot specify -o when generating multiple output files
make : *** [networktablet] error 1

it gives me this error :

Comment: Just curious, where did you get the binary file from? Can you give a link?

Comment: Also, the instructions state that you need gcc, not clang

Comment: Is the binary you are referring to [this one](https://github.com/rfc2822/GfxTablet/blob/binaries/networktablet-x86_64?raw=true) ([source](https://github.com/rfc2822/GfxTablet#part-1-uinput-driver))? Try compiling it at is may work better. This issue may be that your system is not 64bit, or is based on a Ubuntu version older than 12.10 (to check this look for the release name in `/etc/apt/sources.list`), or has had key components replaced.

Comment: Yes this is the same source. 
Yes,my system is not 64bit, so what should I do ?

Comment: You should compile the source. Follow the instructions below the binary download.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why GfxTablet is not working is because you're trying to run a 64-bit binary on a 32-bit installation. Since no 32-bit binary is provided, you should compile the GfxTablet uinput driver with the following instructions from [here](https://github.com/rfc2822/GfxTablet#part-1-uinput-driver):

> 1. Clone the repository:    `git clone git://github.com/rfc2822/GfxTablet.git`
> 2. Install gcc, make and linux kernel header includes (`kernel-headers` on Fedora)
> 3. `cd driver-uinput; make`

Comment: Can you please provide detailed instructions on second step, i.e. the cmds I have to enter in the terminal. Thanks !

Comment: I do all of the steps, it gives this error on the make step : 
clang: error: cannot specify -o when generating multiple output files
make: *** [networktablet] Error 1

Comment: You need to install GCC. Try `sudo apt-get install build-essentials`

Comment: This command isn't found. Installed build-essential.

But the error persists.